# How to output NSString Type in NSLog Function in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I want a input from user their name and output that input name in NSLog using NSString.
I don't know which % sign and how to output that.
Can i use scanf() function for that?
Please help me , i am just beginner of Objective-C.

Comment: See [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Updated Link: [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use %@ for all objects including NSString. This will in turn call the objects `description` method and print the appropriate string. Most objects have a rather useful representation already there (e.g. NSArray objects return the descriptions of all their contents).

Comment: LIKE THAT? NSLog("%@",name); ?

Comment: syntax error FYI. Missing the `@` for the format string. Should be `NSLog(@"%@", name);`

Answer (score 15):

Mark Dylan is the name which would be stored in the Name variable.

```
NSString* Name = @"Mark Dylan";
```

This code will allow you to ask their name and scan it into memory which will be stored in the Name variable.

```
NSLog(@"What is your name?");
scanf("%@", &Name);
```

If you want to print out the variable you can use;

```
NSLog(@"Your name is %@", Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

`%@` is what you want. It fit for object like `NSString`, `[YourViewController class]`

Answer (score 1):

`NSLog` accepts a format string, so you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// 1024 characters should be enough for a name.
// If you want something more flexible, you can use GNU readline:
// <http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html>
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 1024

// Get name from user input
char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
name[0] = '\0'; // just in case fgets fails
fgets(name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH, stdin);

// Put name into NSString object and output it.
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:name];
NSLog(@"%@", name);
```

`%@` works for all Objective-C objects.
If you want to output a C-string (`char*` or `const char*`), use `%s`. Never put a non-literal string as the first argument to `NSLog` as this opens security holes.

Comment: hehe! I just want NSString from User Input. Not Char and output that NSString.and also don't want to convert into NSString.Can i do like that.I am just beginner.Please explain me. :)

Comment: You cannot get an NSString directly from standard input (assuming you want that). You can do it using `NSFileHandle` and `NSData` if you want, but directly using `NSString` is not possible. See http://caiustheory.com/read-standard-input-using-objective-c for an example.

Comment: ah! i know . so we can't get directly String input . IN C#.Net we can easily use Console.ReadLine(); . But in OBJC . we can't get. :( Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

To get input from the user use a [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888) or a [NSTextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  To output a string to the log file you can use NSLog, ie:

```
NSString* userName = @"Zawmin";

NSLog(@"name = %@", userName);
```

Comment: Or an NSTextField if using Cocoa.

Comment: Now i am using Console input from users. How can i do that?

Comment: @Zawmin see my answer. It uses fgets to get a C-string from the user's input. It then converts it to an NSString for output using NSLog.